# Expected number of simultaneous coin tosses until all heads

Tags: probability, statistics

"Four identical coins with probability 0.1 of heads are tossed until they all show heads simultaneously. Find the expected number of trials needed (where each try is to toss all coins)."

My attempt:

Let $X$ be a bernoulli RV such that $X=1$ with probability $(0.1)^4=1/10,000$ and $X=0$ otherwise.

The expected number of throws is therefore $1/p=10,000$

Does this work? Thank you

Comment: The answer is correct. The number $Y$ of trials has geometric distribution, $p=(0.1)^4$, and the mean of the geometric is $1/p$.